# remove step 3 and step 4 in opencart checkout page

Tags: opencart

I want tp jump to payment method if delivery address and billing address are same. How Can I achive in opencart 2.X. Please some body help on this.

Comment: Why do you want to skip delivery method step if both addresses are same?

Comment: This is requirement If I checked that checkbox adress will be same thats why I want to skip please help me out.

Comment: Mohan, OpenCart does this already, perhaps your theme has overridden the default checkout which you can see in action here: https://demo.opencart.com/